# How can optimize query when use ORDER BY on varchar column?

Tags: mysql, symfony

In my query I using ORDER BY on integer column like :

```
select u.id, u.email, ud.first_name, ud.last_name 
from user u left join user_detail ud on u.id = ud.user_id 
ORDER BY u.id DESC
```

it's normal. But if I use ORDER BY on varchar column like:

```
select u.id, u.email, ud.first_name, ud.last_name 
from user u left join user_detail ud on u.id = ud.user_id 
ORDER BY ud.first_name DESC
```

It too slow. My table have 1400000 records. I tried create index on first_name column but it doesn't seem to work. How can I optimize this case ?

Comment: Don't select everything! You don't need all those records at once, right?

Comment: How is email int column?

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava: Your edit changed the facts. I rolled that back.

Comment: Yes, in fact I only LIMIT ~ 20 records, but I see use ORDER BY on varchar column is quite slow

Comment: @NguyenNhutTien: Add the `limit` to your query. Also run `explain select ...` to see that is going on

Comment: @juergend: I added limit 20, and run explain, the result is : type `ALL`, key `NULL`, scan ~1270000 and Using filesort

Comment: Edit your question and add all that info well formatted into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what is happening

```
SELECT 
      u.id, 
      u.email, 
      ud.first_name, 
      ud.last_name 
FROM user u left join user_detail ud ON u.id = ud.user_id 
ORDER BY u.id DESC
```

The query planner use index on user.id; this index is used in join; After that the sort is on same column so index can be used again

But in this case

```
SELECT 
     u.id, 
     u.email, 
     ud.first_name, 
     ud.last_name 
FROM user u LEFT JOIN user_detail ud ON u.id = ud.user_id 
ORDER BY ud.first_name DESC
```

The query planner still chooses the user.id for joining; So your index you create on ud.first_name is not picked up and is a file sort

You will be required to make a composite key on which can be used for both joining and sorting

Answer (score 0):

It definitely has to do with your way of joining. It is one solution as mentioned before by @shubham to create a composite key. The other would be to make table "user_detail" the first table to select and to create a **clustered** index on first_name column. So something like

```
SELECT 
  u.id, 
  u.email, 
  ud.first_name, 
  ud.last_name 
FROM user_details ud LEFT JOIN user d ON ud.user_id = u.id 
ORDER BY ud.first_name DESC
```

I didn't add the LIMIT because you didn't specify the SQL dialect. However, if you select, limit the results like this the limited selected user_details are joined only and not the whole users table.
The clustered index will do the rest. Nevertheless, it might not be necessary to cluster the index.